# How do I extract these parts from HTML-file using JSOUP?

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have read through your 'how to ask a question section' and edited my post. I hope it is better now:

I have downloaded Text-files containing HTML and am doing text analysis on them. Each text-file consists of various documents (see example below) and I only want to select specific ones.

1. Example of text-file (sample.txt) --> it contains 3 documents: 10-K, EX-31, GRAPHIC:

```html
<DOCUMENT>
  <TYPE>10-K
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Text of first document</TITLE>
    </HTML>
    </TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>
  <TYPE>EX-31
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Text of second document</TITLE>
    </HTML>
    </TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>
  <TYPE>GRAPHIC
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Text of third document</TITLE>
    </HTML>
    </TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Using JSOUP I can select all text contained within the `<type>` tag, however, I only want to select specific documents, not all of them.

```html
public class strip {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // read downloaded 10K-filing to memory
        String fileName = "/temp/sample.txt";

        // parse 10K into a tree structure (requires jsoup-jar)
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File(fileName), "utf-8");

        Elements pElements = doc.select("type");

        for (Element element : pElements) {
            String text = element.text();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```html
10-K Text of first document
EX-31 Text of second document
GRAPHIC Text of third document

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However I only want to select documents of the type 10-K or EX-...

In JSOUP I can only select documents based on the tags, but the text I want to use to identify each document is not contained in the tag. Can anybody point me in the right direction here?

The correct output should be:

```html
10-K Text of first document
EX-31 Text of second document
```

Comment: jsoup is java not javascript, please tag correctly, and please add the code you tried to figure out what was wrong

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service or free code writing service. Show your code attempts and sample html in the question , not in images, if you want help

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Instead post your (simplified but still valid) HTML structure as text so we could copy it and use to build potential solutions. Also try to clarify what are you trying to do (what is expected result based on provided input and what results you are trying to avoid).

Comment: Some links which should help you get better help on Stack Overflow: "[ask]", ["How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262527), "[MCVE]" (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: Sorry about the way I asked the question. I hope this is better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select those elements by using the method `getElementsMatchingOwnText(String regex)` in your case: change this line

```
Elements pElements = doc.select("type");
```

to

```
Elements pElements = doc.getElementsMatchingOwnText("10-K|EX-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "nth-of-type(n)" with html tag to extract text in generic way.
aacording to your text file, output will be as - 
EX-31 Text of second document.

```
String textData = doc.select.("DOCUMENT:nth-of-type(2)").text();
```